# Sublime Text 3 with R-box cannot find R 3.1.2 (probably due to wrong %Rguiexe% path?)

Tags: r, plugins, sublimetext3

I use sublime text 3 and R-box [formerly R-Extended] and R-3.1.2, however, when I want to start R, sublime does not find it and displays the error message below.

The path to R (64 bit) in the explorer is `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64\Rgui.exe`, contrary to that in the R-box config file Rgui.ahk the variable `%Rguiexe%` equals `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\i386\Rgui.exe"`, obviously the wrong path.

```
a) Could the problem be caused by something other than the wrong path?
b) Is there a way to set the path to R in R-box manually?
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it works - Thanks to the friendly support of the package creator.

In the R-box settings in Preferences > Package Setting > R-Box > Settings - User, set the R-directory by entering this code (for R 64 bit, use "R32" for 32 bit)

```
{
    // path to Rgui.exe
    "R64": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.2\\bin\\x64\\Rgui.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled the same problem before.

Solution>

```
1. Install useful plugin - PackageResourceViewer  
   This plugin make it easy to find and edit necessary files.  

2. As JBJ has written above, you should edit setting file.   
   Target file name: "R-Box.sublime-settings"  
   You can find it using PackageResourceViewer plugin.  
   MENU
   Tools> Command Palette> PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource> R-Box  

3. Click "R-Box.sublime-settings", and you will see the file content.
   But, you can't edit it because it is read-only.  

4. Now, you should know the full path of above target file.
   "C:\Users\k\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\R-Box\"
   But, don't be hurry. 
   There's no such file in that file path!! (Very strange thing!)

5. You may try to edit opened file, it will be not easy.
   It is locked-up as read-only folder option.
   So you should uncheck the "read-only" checkbox of target folder.

6. At last, you can edit target file. 
   As JBJ has written, activate the x64 version R path.

   { ... 
         // Your 64 bit version R path here
         "R64": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.2\\bin\\x64\\Rgui.exe"

     ...
   }
```

I hope you don't waste much time as I did.
Happy coding~!